# How to keep list of selected localStorage values after refresh in angular6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have list of localStorage data, i select one option from list but after i am refreshing that selected data went out.

```
selectedColumns: any[] = [];


this.listData =  [
{ field: "id", header: "Id", type: "number", value: "id", width: "100px" },
{ field: "description", header: "Description", type: "", value: "description", width: "150px" },
{ field: "status", header: "Status", type: "select", value: "status", width: "100px" },
{ field: "userName", header: 'Moved By', type: "", width: "100px" },
{ field: "lastName", header: 'Moved By', type: "", width: "100px" },
{ field: "rule", header: 'rule', type: "", width: "100px" },
{ field: "domain", header: 'domain', type: "", width: "100px" },
{ field: "date", header: 'date', type: "", width: "100px" },
{ field: "time", header: 'time', type: "", width: "100px" },
{ field: "address", header: 'Moved By', type: "", width: "100px" }
]

for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
      this.selectedColumns[i] = this.listData [i];
      localStorage.setItem("column_selections", JSON.stringify(this.selectedColumns));
    }

    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("column_selections"))) {
      var lsData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_selections"));
      if (lsData) {
        this.selectedColumns = lsData;
      } else {

        for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
          this.selectedColumns[i] = this.listData [i];
        }

        localStorage.setItem("column_selections", JSON.stringify(this.selectedColumns));
      }
    }

    else if(localStorage!= null){
      if(!localStorage.getItem(this.listData ) || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listData ')).length === 0){
      localStorage.setItem("listData ", JSON.stringify(this.listData ));
    }}

    else {
      for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        this.selectedColumns[i] = this.listData [i];

      }
      localStorage.setItem("column_selections", JSON.stringify(this.selectedColumns));

    }
```

After refresh i want selected localStorage data visible. please help me how to do it or where i went wrong.

Comment: Your example is a) incomplete and b) I can not find any angular code? Where do you call this code? Provide a minimal example on stackblitz which shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions, depending on how you store data. The first, and most common for your scenario I think is to store the variable state, and then reload it on ngOnInit. You can also setup a generic service to handle storing controller state, and reloading the controller state in ngOnInit.

Another solution would be to use a service, and load and store the state there...

```
private _myObj: SomeObj;

get myObj(): SomeObj {
    if (!this._myObj) {
      const tmpObj = sessionStorage.getItem('MyService.myObj');
      this._myObj= (!tmpObj) ? new SomeObj () : Object.assign(new SomeObj , JSON.parse(tmpObj));
    }
    return this._myObj;
  }

  set myObj(myObject: SomeObj) {
    this._myObj = myObject;
    sessionStorage.setItem('MyService.myObj', JSON.stringify(this._myObj));
  }
```

If you are just persisting during a user's session, sessionStorage is the better location, localStorage should only be for items you want to persist "*forever*", like preferences, language selection, etc...